# HttpCookie values not available in cookie

Tags: httpcookie

I'm using the following code but when I logout and log back in and the cookie exists but it has no values.

```
        Dim timeclock_cookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("TimeClock")
        timeclock_cookie.Expires = Date.Today.AddYears(1)
        timeclock_cookie.Values.Add("createdby", UserName)
        timeclock_cookie.Values.Add("createddate", Date.Today.ToString)
        timeclock_cookie.Values.Add("timezone", etz(ddlTimeZone.SelectedValue).timezone)
        timeclock_cookie.Values.Add("tzoffset", etz(ddlTimeZone.SelectedValue).offsetfromutc_minutes.ToString)

        Response.Cookies.Add(timeclock_cookie)

        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?err=15", True)
```